# Smoke won't generate in 3d View. Or at all

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've been working on my ink drop tutorial and i've noticed the 3D view won't produce any smoke effects after baking. i'm in cycles render as instructed. Animation is on internal. I'm running on Mac OSX 10.9. Blender version 2.77

Where the smoke is supposed to be is just the outlining box both in 3d view and in render.

What am I missing? Is it my video card (Nvidia)? My mac book laptop supports 64-bit. It's OSX 10.9. I'm really out of ideas here.

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file?

Comment: Hey Shady, https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4z9emxfp2v0zjr/Test.blend?dl=0 (thats the link to a super basic tutorial with (quick smoke). And even that wont display smoke. I'm running a 64-bit mac so I ruled that out. I just don't get why I don't see smoke

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the answer. Apparently there's an add-on check point for generating smoke that needs to be turned on. Once I did that now I see smoke in my renders.

Comment: can you elaborate? smoke generation works _out of the box_ without enabling any add-ons , there are even some physics shortcuts like `quick smoke`.